# How can I resolve the event log full error upon attempting to add a new connection in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, event-log

I want to add a new connection for a SQL database in my project written with Visual C# 2008 Express. But when I click "Add Connection" in the Database Explorer, I see this error:

> The event log file is full

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is your event log full?** You might try [emptying it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3wah3h5%28VS.80%29.aspx).